# How to set up Cocos2dx in Mac

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I got an error when installing a Cocos2DX V3.0 in my Mac. I used the latest OSX and XCode, but I don't know why the error occurs.

> ZS039:~ vishal.patel$ source ~/.bash_profile -bash: export: `Patel/cocos2d-x-3.0/tools/cocos2d-console/bin': not a valid identifier

Comment: there is no option to install the cocos2d x v3.0. just u need to download and create project using terminal and go to the project  folder. open it in xcode and start work.

Answer (score 1):

In your `bash_profile` your EXPORT command is wrong.

Unless `Patel/` is located at the root of your hard drive then it can't find it.